# Crammed text when printing to EPS with latex interpreter

Tags: matlab-figure

I am trying to save figures as eps files using the latex interpreter, and do some from the command line (matlab -nojvm).

The resulting title and label text is crammed together and letters overlap (screenshot here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3iK1j.png). A sample script to replicate this behavior:

```
hFig = figure(1);
set(hFig,'visible','off')

x = 0:0.1:1;

plot(x,x)

set(gca,'FontSize',12)
axis([0 1 -1 1]);
xlabel('x test test','interpreter','latex'); 
ylabel('sin(x) blah blah','interpreter','latex'); 
titleTextDisp = ['Testing Long Title Name'];
tFig = title(titleTextDisp);
set(tFig, 'interpreter','latex'); 
%plotTickLatex2D('xlabeldy',0.02);

set(gcf,'PaperPositionMode','auto')
set(hFig, 'Position', [0 0 700 500])
figName = ['test.eps'];
print(gcf,'-dpsc2','-painters',figName);
```

The visibility of the figure does not affect the result. I'd appreciate any hints.

Comment: When you make the figure visible and view it in Matlab do you see the same problem with the text?  Also, maybe a long shot, but what are you using to visualize the figure after you have exported it?  I ran your code and it made a figure with correctly spaced text when opened in Mac's preview.